# Good Object Oriented Design When Deleting, C++

Tags: c++

The code below deletes the symbol associated with the stock object just fine. Its just bad object oriented design.

The way that i am searching for each stock symbol is by using a != or == test for NULL.

```
bool hashmap::remove(char const * const symbol, stock &s,
int& symbolHash, int& hashIndex, int& usedIndex)
{
    if ( isAdded == 0 ) return false;
    if ( hashTable[isRemoved].symbol == symbol ) return true; 
    else 
    {
        symbolHash = this->hashStr( symbol ); 
        hashIndex = symbolHash % maxSize;
        usedIndex = hashIndex;
    }
    for ( int integer = 0; integer < maxSize; integer++ )
    {
        if ( hashTable[usedIndex].symbol != NULL &&
             strcmp( hashTable[usedIndex].symbol, symbol ) == 0 )
        {   
            isAdded--; 
            isRemoved = hashIndex; 
            s = &hashTable[usedIndex];
            delete hashTable[usedIndex].symbol; 
            hashTable[usedIndex].symbol = NULL; 
            return true;
            }
        ++usedIndex %= maxSize; // wrap around if needed
    }
    return false;
}
```

Im wondering now, if i delete in a such a way that:

```
hashTable[usedIndex].symbol = hashTable[NULL].symbol
```

Thereby, changing the way I logically test for an empty or found stock symbol. Is their a way to remove my stock symbol without having to redo the aspect of finding and searching?

Is this the correct way to remove in object oriented design?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, "object oriented design" is very ambiguous.

Is `isAdded` a member variable? It isn't clear that it is and creates another dependency on this function that isn't obvious when looking at the signature. Same thing goes for `isRemoved`.

Generally, a function that takes 5 arguments is getting close to showing that there is too much dependencies on this function (nevermind the invisible dependencies in `isAdded`, `isRemoved`, and `hashTable`).

I'm not sure what type `hashTable` is, but you should never have to call `delete` in 2009. You can use `auto_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` (in C++0x). These will take care of freeing your resource when it is not needed anymore. If you are using an STL container, then don't use `auto_ptr` though.

If you would like to use a hashtable in C++, you really should consider using a [hash_map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html). That will be a much better implementation than 99.9999% of us can accomplish.

When using a hash_map, you can call `void erase(iterator first, iterator last)` to erase/delete an element.

Comment: right. This is actually an assignment. My instructor told me i cant delete using delete dt.

Answer (score 2):

How is an insert collision handled?  Most standard solutions—such as a linear search for an open slot, or generating a new hash—make deleting an element problematic.  If deletions are common, consider using a list structure instead.